# Cómo alinear input debajo de un texto

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla donde en el th tengo un texto y un filtro (input) pero no puedo dejarlo alineado de tal forma que quede el filtro debajo de la palabra.

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="personas">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          Personas
          <input
            class="filter"
            matInput
            (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value, 'personas')"
            #input
          />
        </th>
```

en mi class filter hice algo así:

```
.filter{
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

He intentado con las propiedades de align

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al respecto?

Comment: He intentado con las propiedades de align, pero ni una me funciona. @BetaM

Comment: Por favor aunque no haya resultado edita tu pregunta y agrega eso, es un punto de partida y ayuda a mejorar tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr lo que buscas puedes valerte por ejemplo de alguna de las siguientes opciones:

1. Convierte al input en un elemento en bloque, para que de esta forma ocupe todo el ancho de su etiqueta padre (*el th y quede debajo del texto*)

   ```
   .filter {
       /*
         resto de código
       */
       display: block;
   }
   ```
2. Puedes simplemente colocar el texto *Personas* dentro de una etiqueta `p` lo cual lo volverá un elemento en bloque ocupando igualmente todo el ancho disponible de su etiqueta contenedora y enviará el input al siguiente renglón

   ```
   <p>
      Personas
   </p>
   ```

Comment: No hace literalmente nada ;(

Comment: @asas ambas soluciones deben estar aplicando lo que necesitas, si no funcionan es por que seguramente tienes alguna regla CSS o framework afectando esto que propongo

Comment: Ambas opciones presentadas por @BetaM logran el resultado que quieres, a menos qie como él dice, tengas algún css que indique lo contrario.